# Length and sum of longest increasing subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm, subsequence

I wanted to count sum and length of the longest subsequence  in the given array `t`.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class so {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] s = br.readLine().split(" ");
        br.close();
        int[] t = new int[s.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            t[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        }
        int length = 1;
        int sum = t[0];
        int maxSum = 0;
        int maxLength = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < t.length; i++) {
            for (; i < t.length && t[i - 1] <= t[i]; i++) {
                length++;
                sum += t[i];
                System.out.print(t[i] + " ");
            }

            if (length > maxLength) {
                maxLength = length;
                maxSum = sum;
                length = 1;
                sum = 0;
                i--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum is " + maxSum + " length is " + maxLength);
    }
}
```

for the numbers`1 1 7 3 2 0 0 4 5 5 6 2 1` I get output:

`sum is 20 length is 6`

but for the same numbers in reverse order `1 2 6 5 5 4 0 0 2 3 7 1 1` I get output:

`sum is 17 length is 6` which is **not true** because I should get `sum is 12 length is 5`.

Could someone spot the my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You are reseting the `length` and `sum` **only** when you find the next longest sequence but you should reset them **every time** you finish testing a sequence:

Right now, your code accumulates `length` and `sum` until it surpasses `maxLength` but `length` and `sum` are test variables that need to be reset when testing each possible subsequence.

Furthermore, you `sum` variable needs to reset to the current test value at `t[i - 1]` and not to `0`. The reason you are getting a correct result even though this bug is present is because the first item in the LIS for both of your inputs is `0`.

If we input something like (replace two `0`s in the first input with `1`s):

```
1 1 7 3 2 1 1 4 5 5 6 2 1
```

Output is:

```
sum is 21 length is 6
```

But sum should be `22`

In fact, a slightly cleaner way would be to perform initialization of your test variables at the beginning of the loop instead of initializing outside of the loop and then reseting inside:

```
// ...
int length, sum, maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int i = 1; i < t.length; i++) {
   // initialize test variables
   length = 1;
   sum = t[i - 1];
   for (; i < t.length && t[i - 1] <= t[i]; i++) {
       length++;
       sum += t[i];
       System.out.print(t[i] + " ");
   }

   if (length > maxLength) {
       maxLength = length;
       maxSum = sum;
       i--;
   }
}
// ...
```

*NOTE*: I added initialization for `maxLength` and `maxSum` to use the smallest possible integer to allow counting negative numbers as well.